# Short story about a train ride into a sleepy country

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

Two people ride a train into a place where there is some disease that makes everyone fall asleep. They tell each other jokes to stay awake. It was a story in a science fiction anthology for young adults. I read it in the mid 1980s in a school library, but it looked like an older book even then.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but please, make sure to have a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could edit in.

Comment: Just a comment:  I found a story "[Tall Tales on the Iron Horse](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?102137)" where the "passengers" are essentially uploaded consciousnesses, and they can't fall asleep because they will cease to be "alive" (becoming just static memories) if they do.  But it's from 2002, so it's far too late.

Comment: Great find! That is the most similar story I've ever seen to the one I'm looking for. In case anyone else wants to check it out, it can be read for free online at [infinity plus](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/ironhorse.htm).

Answer (score 3):

It's not an exact match, but everyone falling asleep is the premise of "[Clutch of Morpheus](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?77841)" (1946) by Larry Sternig.  It was anthologized in [*Tales of Time and Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34403) (1969), which also included a number of other fairly well-known stories, like Clarke's "All the Time in the World."

In this story it's not a disease but the dust from the tail of a comet that's causing everyone to fall asleep worldwide.  The protagonist of the story is the one person who hasn't been affected, and he's trying to find a way to save everyone else.

Comment: You’re right, that’s not the one I was thinking of, but thank you so much for trying to help me. The one you found is a good story. I just read it. Here’s a link in case anyone else wants to check it out: https://archive.org/details/talesoftimespace00olne